# To print asterisks based on inputs

Tags: shell, unix

I Have to print the number of stars that increases on each line from the minimum number until it reaches the maximum number, and then decreases until it goes back to the minimum number. After printing out the lines of stars, it should also print the total number of stars printed.

I have tried using shell scripting and worked. But is there any other simplified and generic way to achieve this

```
echo "enter the mininum number of stars"
read min
echo "enter the maximum number of stars"
read max
for (( i=$min;i<=$max;i++))
do
   for (( j=$max;j>=i;j-- ))
   do
   echo -n " "
   done
   for (( c=1;c<=i;c++ ))
   do
   echo -n " *"
   sum=`expr $sum + 1`
   done
echo ""
done
d_max=`expr $max - 1`
for (( i=$d_max;i>=$min;i--))
do
   for (( j=i;j<=$d_max;j++ ))
   do
   if [ $j -eq $d_max ]
   then
   echo -n " "
   fi
   echo -n " "
   done
   for (( c=1;c<=i;c++ ))
   do
   echo -n " *"
   sum=`expr $sum + 1`
   done
echo ""
done
echo "Total No. of stars : "  $sum 




     *
     * *
    * * *
   * * * *
  * * * * *
   * * * *
    * * *
     * *
      *
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "simplified and generic way"? It is unclear what you're asking. If you're just looking for a code review, then there's a site for that [codereview.se].

Comment: I am looking for any other approach which can be done in unix script

Comment: Arg, if you're using a shell that supports `(( math operations here ))`, then please join the late 80s and use much improved command subutition with `$( cmd_that_produces_needed_output_here)` rather than back-tic'd command sub. Note that you can then do `((sum++))` rather than `sum=\`eval $sum + 1\``. The only generic I can see to add to your code would be to only optionally prompt user if no input provide, other wise user should be able to call your code with `./makeStar 5 5` (for instance). Good luck.

Comment: You can calculate the total no of stars.

Comment: 5 start with spaces: `printf "%*s\n" 5 x| sed 's/./ */g'`. 3 leading spaces: `|pr -tro 3`

Answer (score 0):

## Shell functions (if supported)

You can define functions if your shell supports them. See for example [Bash functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions).

## Arithmetic sum

You can count the [arithmetic sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) of stars instead of expression evaluation inside loop.

## Bash example

See the Bash example below.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function repeat() {
  for (( x=0; x<$1; x++ )) {
    echo -n "$2"
  }
}

function row() {
  repeat $1 ' '
  repeat $2 ' *'
  echo
}

echo "enter the mininum number of stars"
read min
echo "enter the maximum number of stars"
read max

for (( i=$min; i <= $max; i++ )); do
  row $(( $max - i )) $i
done

for (( i=$(( $max - 1)); i >= $min; i-- )); do
  row $(( $max - i )) $i
done

# arithmetic sum
n=$(( $max - $min ))
a1n=$(( $min + $max ))
sum=$(( (($n + 1) * $a1n + $n * ($a1n - 1)) / 2 ))

echo "Total No. of stars: $sum"
```